# What is Iterator Implementation in Linked List using Java?

Tags: java, linked-list

I was creating an inventory to store books information. And I have done with insertion, deletion, search and other function. 
Then, I saw the exercise requirement has a line said that:

You are also required to implement an Iterator for your linked list.

I look up online for the Iterator and watched some videos, still couldn't understand what an iterator is and how to implement into my linked list.

Anyone can help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An iterator basically allows you to iterate over a Collection. I don't know what is meant by:

> You are also required to implement an Iterator for your linked list

But I assume, it want's you to iterate over your Collection using an Iterator and do your operations like this.

Iterating through a Collection using an Iterator:

```
List<Object> list = new LinkedList<>();
Iterator<Object> it = list.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    Object obj = it.next();
    // Do stuff
}
```

If this is not what you are looking for, it seems I missunderstood the question.

Comment: Yes I believe this is what I need to do. However, the problem is I have create the linked list and done the insertion, deletion and other function using Node. How to implement the iterator into this ? It seems like I have to redo the whole linked list with iterator.

Comment: I assume that is what is meant by it. If it's so, it should have been explicitly specified from the start. Glad I could help.

Comment: The question tells this on the last sentence... which my lecturer had only taught the Node method. Is it possible if I just implement it into one function let say the display list function only ?

Comment: Well, as I said, I do not understand exaclty what is meant by that, it could also be a possiblity to ask you to implement your own custom Iterator, like @Kamil Banaszczyk also said underneath.

Comment: I see, I guess I will have to find my lecturer and confirm about this, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Linked list already implements Iterable interface (through other dependencies), which indicates that it needs to have iterator() method which retunrs Iterator object, which allows you to Iterate through list. Iterating is obtaining every next existing element without keeping previous ones in memory.

Iterator has to implement two methods - which is next() - obtain next element if exists, and throw noSuchElementException if don't exist, and hasNext() which returns true or false.

In your excersice i think you may need to implement your custom implementation of Iterator for your own wrapper to Linked List to gain knowledge about how Iterator is build and what is it purpose.

Comment: I see, got it. I will try in my program and see if it's working. Thanks!